# Jquery data split php

Tags: javascript, jquery, split

I have this `array = var1;var2;var3;var4;var5;var6;var6`

and I want to split it with jQuery and put it in different textboxes (txt1),(txt2)...etc,
but I can't find the right code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cb_motor").change(function() {
        $("#cb_motor option:selected").each(function() {
           cb_motor = $('#cb_motor').val();
            $.post("http://localhost/sag_app/index.php/motor/motor/buscar_id/", {
                cb_motor : cb_motor
            }, function(data) {
              valores  = data.split(';');                       
            });
        });
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide relevant HTML markup too, txt1, txt2, etc??? Is ID attribute or what?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming cb_motor is a select with no *multiple*, the code can be simplified

```
$(function() {
  $("#cb_motor").change(function() {
    $.post("http://localhost/sag_app/index.php/motor/motor/buscar_id/", {
      cb_motor : $(this).val()
    }, function(data) {
      var valores  = data.split(';');         
      $('[name="txt_num_serie_motor"]').each(function(i) {
        $(this).val(valores[i]);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

if it IS multiple, then you cannot do Ajax using each for the selected values since you need to wait for each call to return

Comment: <td> <input name="txt_num_serie_motor" type="text" id="txt_num_serie_motor" value="" size="20" readonly></td>

thats mine textbox, do i have to add something?

Answer (score 0):

If `txt1, txt2` are inputs ID and is set following DOM order, you could use:

```
$("[id^=txt]").val(function(i){
    return valores[i];
});
```